# How can I hide an element on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code enables accordion with jQuery.
When I click on `accordion dt` element, accordion opens, and it closes if I click it again.

As default, it's opened but it closes after whole page load.
This looks really strange so that I want to hide it as default.
Is it possible?

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    $(".accordion dt").click(function(){
        $(this).next("dd").slideToggle();
        $(this).next("dd").siblings("dd").slideUp();
        $(this).toggleClass("open");   
        $(this).siblings("dt").removeClass("open");
    });
});

window.onload = function(){     
        $(".accordion dd").hide();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion">
    <dt><h3>Menu</h3></dt>
    <dd>
    Menu Contents
    </dd>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you put your `hide()` function inside of first page load handler?

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    $(".accordion dd").hide();

    $(".accordion dt").click(function(){
        $(this).next("dd").slideToggle();
        $(this).next("dd").siblings("dd").slideUp();
        $(this).toggleClass("open");   
        $(this).siblings("dt").removeClass("open");
    });
});
```

Anyway I would recommend you to put it as a CSS rule:

```
.accordion dd { display: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks this looks the best one

Answer (score 2):

Correctly set the initial element styles so it is rendered in the correct state to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="accordion" style="display:none;">
    <dt><h3>Menu</h3></dt>
    <dd>
    Menu Contents
    </dd>
</div>
```

or on your css

```
accordion{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I believe you meant `.accordion`

Comment: I was suggesting an edit, but I can edit myself if you want me to.